# How do I update a dynamically created number with an AJAX success function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongodb

I'm creating a voting system with a mongo backend, and I'm trying to figure out how to update the number on the front end after a vote is placed. Right now the number is being displayed dynamically with handlebars. On .up click the ajax does it's thing and sends data to the server, then returns gameData. Basically I'm wanting my {{currentvote}} number to update on success.

```
$('.up').on('click', function() {
    var id = this.id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/upvote",
        data: JSON.stringify({ cardId: id }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(gameData){
            console.log(gameData.currentvote + 1);

        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
});

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="up" id="{{ID}}"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up color-gray upvote"></i></div>
    <div class="down" id="{{ID}}"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down color-gray downvote"></i></div>
    <div class="margin-left"><p class="vote-number" id="green">{{currentvote}}</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `$('#green').text(gameData.currentvote + 1)`?

Comment: @YongQuan That won't work on several levels.

Comment: Can you update your snippet so that we get a bigger picture so that we know how exactly it should work?

Answer (score 1):

As you are doing it in jquery ajax you should get it done by jquery too. You can easily do it like this way:

```
success: function(gameData){
    var currentVote = $(".vote-number").text();
    $(".vote-number").text( parseInt(currentVote) + parseInt(gameData.currentvote) + 1 );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Plain old JS ought to do the job.

```
$('.up').on('click', function() {
var id = this.id;
var upVote = document.getElementById('green');
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/api/upvote",
       data: JSON.stringify({ cardId: id }),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(gameData){
            console.log(gameData.currentvote + 1);
            upVote.innerText= parseInt(upVote.innerText) + 1;


        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Updated to take Brad’s comment into account.

Comment: Not that it matters a ton in this case, but you should be setting the text of the element, not the HTML.  Later on, it's entirely likely this code will be modified for other things and you'll be injecting potentially invalid HTML into a place where HTML should be.